# WiX company folder not created

Tags: wix, installation, directory-structure, wix3

I have this fragment to define my directory structure:

```
<Fragment>
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
     <Directory Id="COMPANYFOLDER" Name="MyCompany">
       <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="HDSS.Net">
         <Directory Id="EN" Name="en"/>
       </Directory>
     </Directory>
   </Directory>
   <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"/>
 </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

I have this component group with my application components:

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
  ....
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

in my feature definition I refer to this group:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="HDSS.Net" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
  ...
<\Feature>
```

My problem is that upon installation only the application folder 'HDSS.Net' is created in Program Files and the application folder is not created inside of the 'MyCompany' folder as I would have expected. How can I ensure that this happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup code you provided thus far looks correct.

Some other part of your installation must be changing `APPLICATIONFOLDER` so that it ends up resolving to `[ProgramFilesFolder]HDSS.Net`. Search around for other references to `APPLICATIONFOLDER`.

Alternatively, take a look at a verbose log file. It should show you when `APPLICATIONFOLDER` is being overridden.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I used: <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" /> to allow a user to change the installation directory, and the culprit was: <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" ... \> not including the company folder in the default path.